# Facebook Messenger Bot: Detect When Video Attachment Playback?

Tags: bots, facebook-messenger, botframework, botkit

Is it possible to detect when a user has completed playing a video attachment within Facebook Messenger using the Messenger Platform API?

How about when a user has started playing the video attachment? Or how much time they spent watching the video attachment in total?

Comment: Interesting question. I'm also interested in this. One follow up, when I'm sending videos to users as video url attachment, it seems that actually the whole file is transferred. Do you have a similar experience? I'd really love to send only URL, so user can stream the video instead of pre-downloading it and then playing

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible. No reference to this in the API docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/video-attachment